# Name Union Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0

I am working on a project that uses Union types extensively and consistently throughout the project.  I'd like to name a particular union type, so that I don't have to keep explicitly defining the union throughout my code (introducing the probability of getting it wrong somewhere).

For example, rather than:

```
function doSomething(parm: FirstType | SecondType){...}
function doSomethingElse(parm: FirstType | SecondType){...}
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
class compositeType = FirstType | SecondType;
function doSomething(parm: compositeType) {...}
function doSomethingElse(parm: compositeType) {...}
```

This would help adhere to the DRY principle, and reduce errors in my codebase.  Is this possible in Typescript?  Note: I do not control FirstType and SecondType, as they are returned from third party libraries, so using inheritance is not an option here, AFAIK.

Comment: I've looked at the typescript documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), but I don't see what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases)

```
type FirstOrSecond = FirstType | SecondType;
```